# How long is valid an inhouse distribution certificate from Apple PKI

Tags: ios, pki, in-house-distribution

I have impression that the certificate lifetime validity periods have been changed during the years.

How long is valid an inhouse distribution certificate from Apple PKI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Production In-House Distribution Certificate is valid for 3 years